# How to use shell to solve the scripts and about file?

Tags: shell, awk

I have a question:

#### file:

```
154891
145690
165211
190189
135901
290134
```

I want to output like this: (Every three uid separated by comma)

```
154891,145690,165211
190189,135901,290134
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Nice! Please show your attempts. Read [ask] for a better experience.

Answer (score 2):

There could be many ways to do that, pick one you like, with/out `comma ","`:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%3?",":RS)}' file
154891,145690,165211
190189,135901,290134

$ xargs -n3 -a file  
154891 145690 165211
190189 135901 290134
```

Comment: wo just test the website ,it is my first to register it

Comment: Nice, but you probably meant `xargs -n 3 printf '%s,%s,%s\n' < file` (as an aside: `-a` is a _GNU_ `xargs` extension).

Answer (score 2):

```
sed ':1;N;s/\n/,/;0~3b;t1' file
```

or

```
awk 'ORS=NR%3?",":"\n"' file
```

Comment: Nice, but note that the `sed` solution requires _GNU_ `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pr`:

```
pr -3 -s, -l 1
```

Print in 3 columns, with commas as separators, with a 'page length' of 1.

```
154891,145690,165211
190189,135901,290134
```